# set the font in a beamer presentation to Computer Modern Roman

Tags: beamer, fonts

How can I set the default beamer font to the Computer Modern Roman font?

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\usefonttheme{serif}` to get the default serif fonts.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \lipsum[1]
    \[x^2=25\]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may add

```
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to get nice scalable fonts.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \lipsum[1]
    \[x^2=25\]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```